# jQuery DRY Coding with .toggle / event

Tags: jquery

This is my first attempt at using jQuery and am extremely happy with how it works, but I have some redundant code that I cant help feel could be consolidated. Is there a DRY approach to the following functionality?:

```
<script>
 // Button toggles div
$("#first-button").click(function(){
    $("#first-div").toggle();
});

$("#second-button").click(function(){
    $("#second-div").toggle();
});

$("#third-button").click(function(){
    $("#third-div").toggle();
});

 // if click not on button or div then hide div
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#first-button, #first-div').length) {
        $('#first-div').hide();
    }
});

$(document).on('click', function(event1) {
    if (!$(event1.target).closest('#second-button, #second-div').length) {
        $('#second-div').hide();
    }
});

$(document).on('click', function(event2) {
    if (!$(event2.target).closest('#third-button, #third-div').length) {
        $('#third-div').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: what does html relationship look like for these elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function make_toggler(button_selector, toggle_selector){
 $(button_selector).click(function(){
    $(toggle_selector).toggle();
 });
 $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest(button_selector+", "+toggle_selector).length) {
        $(toggle_selector).hide();
    }
 });
}

make_toggler("#first-button", "#first-div");
make_toggler("#second-button", "#second-div");
make_toggler("#third-button", "#third-div");
```

Comment: Fair enough, they’re out.

Answer (score 0):

If your document is laid out in a consistent way (i.e. if each button and div are similarly related in the HTML), you could simply give them a class and apply the jQuery to it.

Say the target div is the sibling immediately after your button:

```
$('.toggler').click( function(){
  $(this).next('.toggle').toggle();
})
```

Using classes and HTML relationships you can keep your HTML and your jQuery simple and readable.